# Making the search field fit the width of its given space

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar similar to [this](http://codepen.io/DrOverbuild/pen/PGyLpW/), and my problem is I want the search field to stretch to the end of the `.PageMenu` container. I have tried to use `100%` on these elements:

- The `.search_query` element, which puts the search field on the next line while keeping the same Y position.
- The `.SearchForm` Element, which also puts the search field on the next line, but it's also moved to the start of the line.

I've tried a few other things, but not really sure where to go from here.

All the code and stuff is in the CodePen Link: http://codepen.io/DrOverbuild/pen/PGyLpW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using flex-boxes. Then increase the elements inside to width: 100%

The relevant changes in the code would be:

```
#SearchForm {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
#SearchForm form {
  width: 100%;
}
#search_query {
  width: calc(100% - 22px); /* minus the width of the button */
}
```

Full version on [codepen](http://codepen.io/q1k/pen/JbPvwr)

Answer (score 0):

The property 'width' inherits directly from the parent element, so if you want element that's low in the DOM hierarchy to be 100% of the page for example, you have to make sure that all its parents are, or make it independent of the DOM or something else. Here's a small sample of what I think you're wanting, a few links and a search bar beside them that stretches to fill the rest of the screen. Just save this in a html file and open it in the browser:

### **index.html**

```
<div id="pageMenuContainer" style="width:100%;min-width:350px;">
  <a href="#">Contact us</a>
  <a href="#">Shipping</a>
  <a href="#">Potato</a>
  <div style="float:right;width:calc(100% - 200px)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." style="width:100%;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```